# ASP.NET MVC read controller other entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 entities Orders and Items with OrdersController and ItemsController.
In my Orders Index View I have a webgrid

```
grid.Column(columnName: "OrderNo", header: "Order No.", canSort: true),
grid.Column(columnName: "OrderDate", header: "Order Date", canSort: true),                                                                                        
grid.Column(" ", " ", format: @<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Items", new { id = item.OrderNo })">Items</a>)
```

In ItemsController I've added to Index a parameter :

```
public ActionResult Index(string id = "0")
    {
        var orderq = from a in db.items
                        where a.OrderNo== id
                        select a;
        return View(orderq.ToList()); // ex : orderq.Count = 2
    }...
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    } // Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

But I get *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Q : What do I have to to open the items view from my orders ?

Do I have to clear my context and declare it again ?

Comment: Where do you get the error? Do you hit the database / do you have anything in your context when you query orderq in the action?

Comment: for ex in Items Index : return View(orderq.ToList()); // orderq.Count() = 2

Comment: In Debug mode, after the above line it enters  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) method, after that *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Answer (score 0):

Order.cshtml

```
grid.Column(" ", " ", format: @<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Items", new { id = item.OrderNo})">Items</a>)));
```

ItemsController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index(string id = "0")
    {
        var itemsqry = db.items.Where(a=>a.OrderNo == id);
        return View(itemsqry .ToList());
    }
```